# can't insert data into database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have writen some code in php for user registration but if i click on submit button It is not writing in database.Please help me.   Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Register - Vatsal Technosoft Messenger</title>

    <link href="Style/regstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

    <div id="outer">
        <div id="companyname"></div>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="formcontainer">
                <h3>Registration Form </h3>
                <form name="register_form" action="" method="post">
<?php
if( isset($_POST['register']) AND 
    isset($_POST['username']) AND 
    isset($_POST['password']) AND 
    isset($_POST['firstname']) AND 
    isset($_POST['lastname']) AND 
    isset($_POST['contact1']) AND 
    isset($_POST['address']) AND  
    isset($_POST['jobtitle'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $con1 = $_POST['contact1'];
        $con2 = $_POST['contact2'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $jobtitle = $_POST['jobtitle'];

    if( empty($username) or 
        empty($password) or 
        empty($fname) or 
        empty($lname) or 
        empty($con1) or 
        empty($email) or 
        empty($address) or 
        empty($jobtitle)) {

          $message = "All Information Is neccessary";

    } else {

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (``,` $username `,` $password `,` $fname `,` $lname `,` $con1 `,` $address `,` $jobtitle `)");

        if($sql) {                  
            $message = "OK....!";       
        } else {       
            $message = "BAD";       
        }
    }
        echo  "<div class='box'> $message </div>";
    }
?>


                    <div id="formtext">
                        User Name :     <input type="text" name="username" style="width:200px;" autocomplete="off"/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Passwrod  :     <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" style="width:200px;"/>
                        <br /><br />

                        First Name :    <input type="text" name="firstname"  style="width:200px;" autocomplete="off" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Last Name  :    <input type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete = "off" style = " width:200px; "/>
                        <br /><br />

                        Contact(1) :    <input type="text" name="contact1" autocomplete="off" style="width:200px;" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Contact(2) :    <input type="text" name="contact2" autocomplete="off" style="width:200px;"/>
                        <br /><br />

                        E-mail ID &nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" style="width:300px;"/>
                        <br /><br />

                        Address :<br />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        <textarea name="address" cols="25" rows="5" autocomplete="off" style="background: #333;color: #fff;border-radius:5px;border: 0px; margin-top:-20px;" placehoder="Address"></textarea>
                        <br /><br />
                        Job Title &nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="jobtitle" autocomplete="off" style="width:215px;"/>
                        <br /><br /><br />

                        <input type="button" name="back" value="Back" style="width:100px; margin-left:95px;"/>
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="width:100px; margin-left:45px;"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" style="width:100px; margin-left:45px;"/>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need more information. Are there any errors? Oh, and don't forget to protect your site from SQL injections. Use prepared queries...

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `mysql_query`. Try adding a call to `mysql_error()` and it'll show you what the error is. At a guess - your quoting in the query is wrong (backticks are around column and table names, not values), and you're also adding a blank field as the first value - if that's the primary key of the table and it's auto_increment, you're better off omitting it.

Comment: you need to learn PHP. This code has broken all my standards of PHP. xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably this line:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (``,` $username `,` $password `,` $fname `,` $lname `,` $con1 `,` $address `,` $jobtitle `)");
```

It is recommended to always declare your column names in the INSERT statement like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`col1` , `col1` , `col3`) VALUES ('val1' , 'val2' , 'val3')");
```